# How to convert this query in derived table concept

Tags: mysql, distance, latitude-longitude

**Updated :**

How to introduce this below query in derived tables

( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(36.247137) ) * cos( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) * cos( radians(`cm`.`lng` ) - radians(-115.221032) ) + sin( radians(36.247137) ) * sin( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance

in this MySql query :

MySql Query :

```
SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(36.247137) ) * cos( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) * cos( radians(`cm`.`lng` ) - radians(-115.221032) ) + sin( radians(36.247137) ) * sin( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance, min(pl.price_pure) as minPrice, max(pl.price_pure) as maxPrice, min(pl.`squarefeet_pure`) as minSquare, max(pl.`squarefeet_pure`) as maxsquare FROM  `plans` pl INNER JOIN property pr ON pr.id = pl.property_id INNER JOIN communities cm ON cm.id = pr.community_id Having distance < 20 order by pl.price_pure, pl.squarefeet_pure
```

**..........................................................................**

Prev query heading was :
Why no result when applying Max, MIN price formula in MySql query

Detailed question:

http://pastebin.com/UR48mbtq here is my mysql query .. i want to get the max and min price of homes which are falling under 20 miles distance.. but the result is null. Distance in example is 20 but i have also result in my database with 20 miles and less 20 miles

MySql Query :

```
SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(36.247137) ) * cos( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) * cos( radians(`cm`.`lng` ) - radians(-115.221032) ) + sin( radians(36.247137) ) * sin( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance, min(pl.price_pure) as minPrice, max(pl.price_pure) as maxPrice, min(pl.`squarefeet_pure`) as minSquare, max(pl.`squarefeet_pure`) as maxsquare FROM  `plans` pl INNER JOIN property pr ON pr.id = pl.property_id INNER JOIN communities cm ON cm.id = pr.community_id Having distance < 20 order by pl.price_pure, pl.squarefeet_pure
```

With this Result:

```
distance              minPrice   maxPrice   minSquare   maxsquare
1754.3401139613718       0       21000003     0            8607
```

But when i am adding Having clause then result is null with below query

```
SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(36.247137) ) * cos( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) * cos( radians(`cm`.`lng` ) - radians(-115.221032) ) + sin( radians(36.247137) ) * sin( radians( `cm`.`lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance, (pl.price_pure) as minPrice, (pl.price_pure) as maxPrice, (pl.`squarefeet_pure`) as minSquare, (pl.`squarefeet_pure`) as maxsquare FROM  `plans` pl INNER JOIN property pr ON pr.id = pl.property_id INNER JOIN communities cm ON cm.id = pr.community_id Having distance < 20 order by pl.price_pure, pl.squarefeet_pure
```

**Update :**
if i am removing max, min formula from query then also its giving me 400 result ..

Comment: instead of having can you try with where ?

Comment: @krishnpatel its virtual field and i thing where cant apply here. also i tried before.

Comment: CAST(Distansc login  AS UNSIGNED) AS distance. can you try it

Comment: distance < 20   mean 1754.34 < 20 is false. you should write **>** to get this data

Comment: @krishnpatel i want to find the result upto 20 miles.. that should not be greater than 20 miles..

Answer (score 1):

`Having` is a clause that is applied after the query rows are generated. Since you have aggregate functions in your query, but no `GROUP BY`, mysql provides you a single (sample) `distance` result and then the min and max for the entire dataset.

After that, the `having` clause is applied - and as @krishnpatel pointed out, 1754 < 20 is false, so that row is dropped and you're left with nothing.

Add a `GROUP BY` in your selection, equivalent to your `distance` calculation, to return the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First gather ids for the properties within 20 miles.

Then use that as a subquery and `JOIN` to the main table to do the rest:

```
SELECT MIN(...), ...
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE ... < 20 ) AS x
    JOIN tbl ON x.id = tbl.id;
```

No `HAVING`, no `GROUP BY` (unless I missed something).